# code crashes when accessing a predefined array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having trouble understanding why my code crashes when accessing the array. When converting the function param to `int[3][3]` instead of `int**` I get no problems, but I can't understand why, since the `int**` I'm given as a argument is a valid pointer that points to local memory defined in `main`

```
typedef struct {const unsigned int m; const unsigned int n;} mat_size;

void print_mat(int** mat, mat_size s){  // <-- faulty version
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < s.m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < s.n; j++){
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    printf("=============");
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int matrix[3][3] = {{1,4,2},{7,-1,15},{33,-10,-1}};
    mat_size s = {3,3};
    print_mat(matrix, s);  

    while(1);
    return 0;
}

void print_mat(int mat[3][3], mat_size s){  // <-- good version
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < s.m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < s.n; j++){
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
    printf("=============");
}
```

Comment: because `matrix[3][3]` isn't a `int**` but `*int[3]`

Comment: but shouldn't it access the same memory location?

Comment: @noob No, not at all. After all, an `int**` is a pointer to a pointer. While a `*int[3]` contains pointers to integers. How can code that expects pointers to pointers work if you give it pointers to integers?

Comment: I see. I used the ** since I want the size to be dynamic. How can I declare this function if I want both dimensions of the array to be determined in run-time?

Comment: If you're gonna work with multi-dimensional arrays, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: `int[3][3] mat` isn't even valid C and won't compile.

Comment: @Lundin typo. I corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of function parameter does not match the passed matrix because `matrix[3][3]` isn't a `int**` but `(*int)[3]`.

From comment you also want to have dynamic sizes for your matrix so you can do that using [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    const unsigned int m;
    const unsigned int n;
} mat_size;

void print_mat(mat_size s, int (*mat)[s.n])
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < s.m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < s.n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("=============\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int matrix[3][3] = { { 1, 4, 2 }, { 7, -1, 15 }, { 33, -10, -1 } };
    mat_size s = { 3, 3 };
    print_mat(s, matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx! I tried using the mat_size s.n as argument but didn't succeed so I thought of sending mat as void* and then casting it inside the function, but this looks way better

Comment: If I now want to create a new function that returns a dynamically-determined-sized-array, how would I do that? I cant declare a "int [][] f(){}"... so should I declare a void* and then cast it?

Comment: You should think to use a struct with pointer to dynamic allocated array and dim. So you can return a simple struct pointer. Otherwise you can pass output arrays pointer ans sizes as parameters to function.

Answer (score 1):

An array that is declared as a function parameter gets silently adjusted by the compiler to the first object. This is why

```
void func (int a[5]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void func (int* a);
```

Similarly, an array that is declared by the caller and passed to such a function, also "decays" into a pointer to the first element.

The rationale behind this is that arrays shouldn't get passed by value to functions, since taking a hard copy of an array takes up execution time and memory.

---

In the case of multi-dimensional arrays, the same rules apply. Given a function `void print_mat(int mat[3][3])`, the array will get silently adjusted to a pointer to the first element. The first element in an `int [3][3]` array is an array of type `int[3]`. Therefore a pointer to such an element must be an *array pointer*, `int (*)[3]`.

Therefore `void print_mat(int mat[3][3])` is equivalent to `void print_mat(int (*mat)[3])`. So you can change the function to use such an array pointer and it would be equivalent.

However, I would recommend using a variable approach instead:

```
void print_mat (size_t x, size_t y, int mat[x][y])
```

---

Pointer-to-pointers have nothing to do with multi-dimensional arrays, though they can be used to emulate one together with dynamic memory allocation. Doing so is however most often bad and incorrect practice. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for more info about that.